# Advanced Custom Fields display unchecked choices

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a field where I want to display both checked and unchecked choices. I have tried many code examples I have found but none of them work. I have managed to display the checked values, but how can I make it show the unchecked values aswell? Here the code I am currently using:

```
<?php while( have_rows('car_info', 51) ): the_row();
$values = get_sub_field('car_what_covered');
if($values) {
foreach($values as $value) { ?>

<div class="point-row"><?php echo $value; ?> (checked)</div>

<?php }
} endwhile; ?>
```

Heres also a image of my field setup if it helps.

[image]

Comment: not very clear, which part of the form ? do you mean input checkbox ?

Comment: Did you check the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$values = get_field('car_what_covered');
$field = get_field_object('car_what_covered');
$choices = $field['choices'];
foreach ($choices as $value => $label) {
    echo $label,': ';
    if (in_array($value, $values)) {
      echo 'checked';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

reference from [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/checkbox-how-to-display-all-item-as-check-uncheck/)